# How to display date in need format from database, from iso8601 to type="date"

Tags: javascript, java, angular, spring, crud

Huy everyone! Have a problem with dislpaying date form DB. I have field expiryDate of project there are in DB: 
Type of DB "date" Example: "2019-12-12"
when i get date form in json in angular like this:
Image of expiryDate (https://i.stack.imgur.com/23uhm.png)
iso8601

I'm creating CRUD function - update and i want display previous date that was before i don't know how. 
image of when i want to display previous date - http://prntscr.com/orrj6d

I tried few examples but they didn't helped

project.ts:

```
this.dateInForm = new Date(expiryDate.dayOfMonth, expiryDate.monthValue - 1, expiryDate.year);
console.log(this.dateInForm); // => Tue Jun 11 1918 00:00:00 GMT+0202 (Восточная Европа, летнее время)



// expiryDate format is : 
//chronology: {id: "ISO", calendarType: "iso8601"}
//dayOfMonth: 12
//dayOfWeek: "THURSDAY"
//dayOfYear: 346
//era: "CE"
//leapYear: false
//month: "DECEMBER"
//monthValue: 12
//year: 2019
```

project.html:

```
<div>
<input type="date" style="font-size: 13px;" formControlName="expiryDate" [(ngModel)]="dateInForm"  class="question" class="form-control" placeholder="expiryDate" required autocomplete="off"/>
<label for="msg"><span></span></label>
</div>
<div *ngIf="updateProjectForm.controls.expiryDate.invalid &&(updateProjectForm.controls.expiryDate.dirty || updateProjectForm.controls.expiryDate.touched)">
<div *ngIf="updateProjectForm.controls.expiryDate.errors?.minDate">
     <p class="err-msg">
       expiryDate is  invalid
     </p>
</div>
 </div>
```

I don't know how to display date in html type="date" please help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the native `input` elements of type `date`, there is no need to convert it to a JavaScript Date object. As stated on the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date), the `value` attribute accepts

> A DOMString representing a date in YYYY-MM-DD format, or empty.

you should be binding the input element to a string value of `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

On your component.html,

```
<input type="date" style="font-size: 13px;" [(ngModel)]="dateInForm"  class="question" class="form-control" placeholder="expiryDate" required autocomplete="off"/>
```

And on your component.ts,

```
dateInForm: string = '';

// other parts of the code

this.dateInForm = `${expiryDate.year}-${expiryDate. monthValue}-${expiryDate. dayOfMonth}`;
```

I have created a demo over [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-seogws?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Comment: Thank you for help. Yes the required format is "yyyy-MM-dd". but i get in json from back format iso8601 like in the link (https://i.stack.imgur.com/23uhm.png). How can  i display this date in my input field?

Comment: @DenisDeniben You're welcome! And yes, `this.dateInForm = `${expiryDate.year}-${expiryDate. monthValue}-${expiryDate. dayOfMonth}`;` will set the date to be in `yyyy-MM-dd` format!

Comment: In another computer when i started it doesn't work! The specified value "2019-8-21" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

Comment: Because when i getting date form base i have format 2019-8 (must be 08)-21 how fixed?

Comment: I got out like: ```
      if (monthValue < 10) {
        monthDate = `0${monthValue}`;
      }
      if (dayOfMonth < 10) {
        this.dayDate = `0${dayOfMonth}`;
      } else {
        this.dayDate = this.projectData.expiryDate.dayOfMonth;
      }
      this.dateInForm =
        `${year}-${monthDate}-${dayDate}`;
    });```

Comment: Oh, right! I just realised what you meant. Yes, that is an issue indeed. It has to be in `MM` rather than `M` format. Glad you figured it out :)